# Why doesnt this method return a string?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, object, printing

I am working on quite a big program, and I ran into a wierd problem.
this is a code snippet:

```
newColor = Player.changeColor
a = [newColor]
```

this is (a simplified version of) the method in the Player object (it's called by a method in another class):

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
chosenColor = random.choice(colors)
    return chosenColor
```

But when I print the variable a, this is what i get (instead of the string of a color):

```
[<bound method Player.changeColor of <__main__.Player object at 0x0241B510>>]
```

how can i fix it (so that it will print a string of the random color instead of this)?

Comment: I don't think the whole code would help you - it's a 500+-lines code about a not-so-popular local card game (Taki), so I didn't give it and you probably shouldn't ask for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call functions in order to get them to execute and return something.

```
newColor = Player.changeColor()
```

Or, if `changeColor` isn't a static method of the Player class,

```
newColor = Player().changeColor()
```

Comment: Right, I forgot! Thank you very much!
(the site doesn't let me approve this answer this soon, so I comment to prevent others from wasting their times answering me)

Comment: @GalA. You should probably just delete the question. Questions about silly errors like this are not useful to the site.